# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in after decoding a json file in php

Tags: php, json

Using Php 7.2

**Summary of the project.**

- I am pulling a json file from the web into my php script.
- Decode the json.
- Render the info in an html table.

Here is the Script

```
<?php
$url_meta               =   "LINK_TO_json" ;
$data_meta              =   file_get_contents($url_meta);
$result_meta            =   json_decode($data_meta);
?>


<table id="data-armours-1" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
                <th  class="align-middle">test</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach($result_meta["Product"] as $key => $value) 
        {;?>
        <tr>
            <td class="align-middle"><?php echo $value["IsSuspended"];?></td>
            <td class="align-middle"><?php echo $value["*****"];?></td>
            <td class="align-middle"><?php echo $value["*****"];?></td>
            <td class="align-middle"><?php echo $value["*****"];?></td>
            <td class="align-middle"><?php echo $value["*****"];?></td>
            <td class="align-middle"><?php echo $value["*****"];?></td>
            .....
        </tr>
        <?php
        }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Var dumb for the $result_meta

```
var_dump ($result_meta );


string(2957684) "
{"Product":[
{
"IsSuspended":false,
"IsBlocked":false,
"IsPublishedOnWeb":true,
"IsServiceItem":false,
"IsSpecialProduct":false,
"Brand":"BraND",
"ProductionOrigin":1,
"HasVariationParent":false,
"HasVariationChild":false,
"IsTaxExempt":false,
"IsDiscountable":true,
"ProductDimensions":{
    "StockCode":"AB1010",
    "Length":235.00,
    "Height":160.00,
    "Width":20.00,
    "DimensionUnit":"mm",
    "Mass":0.20,
    "MassUnit":"Kg"
},
"TariffCode":"95030090",
"TariffDescription":"ABACUS",
"ProductDefaultCard":"",
"BarcodeType":"GTIN13",
"RetailPriceIncTax":*****,
"CustomerDiscount":*****,
"FriendlyTitle":"",
"PrintDescription":"",
"VariationMetaData":{
    "StockParentId":-1,
    "VariationFriendlyTitle":"",
    "VariationFriendlyStockCode":"",
    "OriginalStockCodeSuffixAndFootnote":""
},
"AttributeData":null,
"CompositeVariationFootnote":"",
"ExternalSiteWebURL":"",
"CustomerProductCode":null,
"TaxRate":0.150000,
"MaxDiscount":100.00,
"StockID":*****,
"StockCode":"*****",
"CustomerPrice":*****,
"CustomerTaxAmount":******,
"CustomerPriceWithTax":******,
"Description":"",
"ProductBarCode":"",
"FuturePrice":null,
"DetailedDescription":"
    \r\n
    Helps teach math skills
    \r\n
    
    \r\n
    
    \r\n

",
"RetailPrice":,
"IntermediatePacks":[
    {
        "PackBarCode":"",
        "PackQTY":,
        "StockCode":""
    },
    {
        "PackBarCode":"",
        "PackQTY":100,
        "StockCode":""
    }
],
"AlternativeProducts":[],
"ProductImageLinks":[""],
"ProductDocumentLinks":null,
"KitItems":[],
"PromotionInfo":null,
"WarehouseStockLevels":[    
    {
        "Amount":,
        "StockCode":"",
        "WarehouseCode":null,
        "WarehouseDescription":""
    }
],
"MainProductImageLink":"",
"TotalWarehouseStock":***,
"PublishingCategory":
    {
        "CategoryID":***,
        "CategoryName":"****"
    }
}
,{
"IsSuspended":false,
"IsBlocked":false,
"IsPublishedOnWeb":true,
"IsServiceItem":false,
"IsSpecialProduct":false,
"Brand":"BraND",
"ProductionOrigin":1,
"HasVariationParent":false,
"HasVariationChild":false,
"IsTaxExempt":false,
"IsDiscountable":true,
"ProductDimensions":{
    "StockCode":"AB1010",
    "Length":235.00,
    "Height":160.00,
    "Width":20.00,
    "DimensionUnit":"mm",
    "Mass":0.20,
    "MassUnit":"Kg"
},
"TariffCode":"95030090",
"TariffDescription":"ABACUS",
"ProductDefaultCard":"",
"BarcodeType":"GTIN13",
"RetailPriceIncTax":*****,
"CustomerDiscount":*****,
"FriendlyTitle":"",
"PrintDescription":"",
"VariationMetaData":{
    "StockParentId":-1,
    "VariationFriendlyTitle":"",
    "VariationFriendlyStockCode":"",
    "OriginalStockCodeSuffixAndFootnote":""
},
"AttributeData":null,
"CompositeVariationFootnote":"",
"ExternalSiteWebURL":"",
"CustomerProductCode":null,
"TaxRate":0.150000,
"MaxDiscount":100.00,
"StockID":*****,
"StockCode":"*****",
"CustomerPrice":*****,
"CustomerTaxAmount":******,
"CustomerPriceWithTax":******,
"Description":"",
"ProductBarCode":"",
"FuturePrice":null,
"DetailedDescription":"
    \r\n
    Helps teach math skills
    \r\n
    
    \r\n
    
    \r\n

",
"RetailPrice":,
"IntermediatePacks":[
    {
        "PackBarCode":"",
        "PackQTY":,
        "StockCode":""
    },
    {
        "PackBarCode":"",
        "PackQTY":100,
        "StockCode":""
    }
],
"AlternativeProducts":[],
"ProductImageLinks":[""],
"ProductDocumentLinks":null,
"KitItems":[],
"PromotionInfo":null,
"WarehouseStockLevels":[    
    {
        "Amount":,
        "StockCode":"",
        "WarehouseCode":null,
        "WarehouseDescription":""
    }
],
"MainProductImageLink":"",
"TotalWarehouseStock":***,
"PublishingCategory":
    {
        "CategoryID":***,
        "CategoryName":"****"
    }
}
]}"
```

**The Problem**

I get the following PHP error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in file/name/:linenumber Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in file/name/:linenumber on line **
```

**Desired outcome**

- Can someone please advise on how I render this JSON data in an html table?
- Please note will not use all the data.
- but will need to know how to use the "IntermediatePacks":[] as well.

Thank you

Comment: What did $data_meta look like?

Comment: If this is the code that's causing that error, then one of the items in `$result_meta["Product"]` is not an array but a string. That assumes the `file/name/:linenumber` part of the error message points to one of the lines that outputs a `$value["*****"]` within your `foreach` loop.

Comment: @rickdenhaan if you look at the var_dump, the whole of $result_meta is one big string. My suspicion is that the source data was double-encoded.

Comment: @ADyson Good point, I assumed that was actually the dump of `$data_meta`. If it's `$result_meta` then your suspicion is probably correct.

Comment: var_dump, the whole of $result_meta is one big string that is correct.

Should I not decode it?

Comment: Yes. But you may need to decode it twice... again please show the content of $data_meta. P.s. if the JSON in the file is indeed double encoded then the real solution here would be to find out how it got like that and fix that.

Comment: $data_meta is a link from the supplier of the products

Comment: No it's not. $url_meta is the link. $data_meta is the raw data downloaded from the link, before you decode it - look at your own code, it makes that clear. We need to see the contents of that to know if the double-encoding theory is correct.

Comment: here is the link to the raw json

https://accounts.parrotproducts.biz:443//PublicWebServices/Customers.svc/GetCustomerProductFeed/1/fDWnCEWn/json

Comment: Yep that's a double-encoded JSON string. The outer quite marks and all the `\\`s to escape the inner ones give it away. That needs fixing, it should not have been saved that like. Get whoever created it to sort it out.

Comment: OK thank you for you time